# c# quartz.net not triggers always

Tags: c#, quartz-scheduler

I have a job, which triggers every 30 minutes. I've set test table and recording information, when job fires.  For example  :

```
2015-11-14 03:00:00.000
2015-11-14 03:30:00.000
2015-11-14 04:00:00.000
2015-11-14 04:30:00.000
2015-11-14 05:00:00.000
2015-11-14 05:30:00.000
2015-11-14 06:00:00.003
2015-11-14 06:30:00.000
```

But it's already second time i've notised that job stop working and not firing. It's already 12:00 pm and last job fired at  06:30:00 time. The solution is publish again application, and override old bin... Why is that happening, is it quartz bug or server? P.s i am using asp.net mvc  and this is code :

```
   ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                   .WithDailyTimeIntervalSchedule
                     (s =>
                        s.WithIntervalInMinutes(30)
                        .OnEveryDay()
                       .StartingDailyAt(TimeOfDay.HourAndMinuteOfDay(0, 0))
                     )
                   .Build();

               scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
```

Also, server was not down, when jobs not fired.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is when the server is not active (not receiving requests), the server is pooling the resources of your web app, you need to set up your server:

http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-application-initialization

or keep your site doing something allways to avoid pooling, i did a job that run every two minutes, it loads a page that has just a short text, here is my code:

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        var stream = webClient.OpenRead("http://example.com/");


        var client = new WebClient();
        var text = client.DownloadString("http://example.com/");

        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://http://example.com/");
        //Get the response
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        //Read the stream from the response
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
```